# Changing URL via AJAX using wicket

Tags: java, ajax, url, wicket

Is there a way to make an AJAX call alter the current page URL without redirecting or reloading the page, in Apache Wicket?

For example, say we are in the URL:

```
localhost:8080/someUrl
```

I'd like that when I click an ajax link, some action is performed, and the URL changes to, say:

```
localhost:8080/otherUrl
```

without redirecting, just changing the URL displayed in the browser.
Is this even possible?

Comment: If you think about it, it would be a massive security flaw if browsers allowed anything like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only part of the url you can change with javascript is the hash

You could change `localhost:8080/#/someUrl` to  `localhost:8080/#/otherUrl`

Do this with `window.location.hash`

Here's an example of a flash site which uses this concept to allow for deep-linking URL's: http://www.2advanced.com

Comment: You can change the URL at the address bar, as @martin-g says in his answer that can be achieved with the History API

Comment: This line does that: window.history.pushState("", "", url);
I am much more interested how to force to the http links use the params from the new URL instead of the old one.

Comment: Did you see the date on this question, @AzatMartirosyan ? HTML5 wasn't used in production then.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can !
But this is not related to Wicket at all.
This is what the new History API in HTML5 is about.
Just search for "html5 History API example" in Google and enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

Help make this feature happen, vote (or contribute!) for https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5290

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't. If you change the location in the browser, a new request is made to that URL.

(You do that with `window.location.href = newUrl`, but the page reloads)